# How to format text in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, formatting, smtplib

I want to format a string where a part of a text or key words are in bold.

For example:

`details = "Your name is: !BOLD!{name}!BOLD!".format(name)`

I want to use this so I can display labels with partly bold text in TKINTER and I want to format text so that key words and values are used to send an email using SMTPLIB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is probably no way to achieve that globally. eg for bold text in terminal you'd need to use some control characters, in emails you'd need `<b>`/`<strong>` HTML tags (also depending on the client used to read the email), etc.

Comment: There is plenty of existing documentation for how to colorize text in a text widget. Have you done any research? Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I think I will try to work on this for now, I have done some research but none successful yet.